# Is it okay to allow customers to create an account with hyphen(-) and underscore(_) in the email address at the end of username?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

I personally think it is a bad idea to let users use _ and - in the end of desired username. Example guru_@abc.com.

My management is asking me for the solid reasons behind me not letting them use these characters in the end of their username.

How do i build this case?

Comment: They are right to ask! why do you need to limit your users freedom of choice?

Comment: i'm not sure you have a case to build!

Comment: @GuruMunishwar: You have quite a few open questions with multiple submitted answers and none accepted. Could you please check them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is **not a good idea** to restrict user from choosing their username combos.
I agree that `johndoe_` looks uglier than `john_doe` but that is not a good enough reason.

What you can instead do is, **suggest the possible list of usernames** once the user fills his first & last name (like twitter). You can **omit `johndoe_` from your suggestion list**. But you must still allow the user to go ahead with it if he wants to.

Also think about the scenario when `johndoe`, `john-doe`, `john_doe` are all taken. Now the user might have an option of going with `_johndoe`, `johndoe_`, or `johndoe1`. In this case, I think that first two are far better options than the last one :)

Answer (score 1):

**If it's going to be used for an email, and is a [valid email address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses), you should allow it**.  It may not be something that many people use often, but that doesn't mean that you shouldn't allow it.  Some people may use this to mark an email address that is used only for potential spam sites, or that is of significance to them in some way.

---

Take the real life parallel of xBox banning users that have a physical address that they don't think is real.  Places like Fort Gay or Cumming (both of which are real towns in the USA).  It's just silly to exclude an address because you think it's not nice or silly.  The user should decide that, not you.

Comment: He isn't talking about validity of email. What he intends to say(as i understood) is about choosing the username on his own site. Since based on the selected username, the email address of that particular user will be generated

Comment: @Jigar The gist seems to be that it's going to be used in an email address, and that is where the issue lies.